# Random forcing preserves outer measure

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I've been told before that if $g$ is random over $V$, then the reals of $V$ have full outer measure in $V[g]$ (and are therefore nonmeasurable). Is there a good reference/easy proof for this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Lemma 2.15 in Brendle's lecture notes:

https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/personen/khomskii/ST2013/bogotalecture.pdf